# iOS WKWebView Swift javascript enable

Tags: ios, swift, web, view, wkwebview

I'm trying to develop a simple app to browse my website. However, my website contains some javascript and it doesn't successfully show my website.

In the past development with Android, the same app was enabling it like this:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

This is my code now and I am missing the option to enable javascript:

```
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "http://132.148.136.31:8082")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

For those who are building for iOS 14 with Swift 5 and Xcode 12, it has changed to the following ...

```
webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
```

Comment: this did not work for me, it still shows that js is disabled in my browser (webview)

Answer (score 17):

Working with `WKWebView` is better to create it from code. And you can set `javaScriptEnabled` to **configuration**:

```
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.preferences = preferences
let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```

**Update. This is WKWebView in view controller class:**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = preferences
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you implement this? I get so many errors If I do it in the view controller class

Comment: @lusito92 I've updated my answer. It works well for me (Xcode 9.0.1, Swift 4). What errors do you have?

Comment: I updated but still not working javascript look on the top the update please let me know really appreciate

Comment: @lusito92 I've double checked it with https://www.google.com. It works! with `.javaScriptEnabled = true` I can open side bar, and if `false` - I cant. Are you sure that JavaScript works on your page by URl http://132.148.136.31:8082 ? Did you try it in Safari? You also could debug you webview with a connected device in Safari on mac.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. there is a function to show an auto fill drop down when clicking a button/ textfield in a webview. and which is working fine on android after enabling the javascript. but it doesn't work for me even if i enable the javascript as per your code above. Any solution..?  would be appreciated. Thanks..!

Answer (score 9):

You are using WKWebView storyboard view so you can directly access the configuration. So use preferences under your WKWebView configuration.

```
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "http://132.148.136.31:8082")
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

    // enable JS
    webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.load(urlRequest)
  }
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner syntax!

Comment: @Md Imran Choudhury how I can check that my JS is loaded successfully.

Comment: You can set any JS action to your website to check.

Comment: Yes I have written JS function to display and evaluated in my swift class it is working. But in my case javascript is not calling is this because of script path which we are setting in HTML ? Is it because of JS interface not calling?

Comment: @MdImranChoudhury when I injected my script into my WKWebview then only I am able to display "JS Alert" after loading HTML. Resolved issue!

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is right you need to set this value as true to enable JavaScript.

```
webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

But if the JS scripts are from a non-HTTPS source then you need to allow **"App Transport Security's Arbitrary Loads"**.

Here is how to fix that:

1. Navigate to Project Settings/Target/[your app's target]/Info.
2. Check whether there is a dictionary called App Transport Security Settings. If not, create it.
3. Inside it, create a boolean value called Allow Arbitrary Loads (if it's not there yet) and set it to YES.

[image]

Comment: 'javaScriptEnabled' was deprecated in iOS 14.0: Use WKWebPagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript to disable content JavaScript on a per-navigation basis

Answer (score 2):

IOS 15.5

add this

```
webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the official documentation of `javaScriptEnabled` or `allowsContentJavaScript`, it says:

`The default value of this property is true.`

So, you don't even need to write this if you don't disable it somewhere else.

**However, if you need to enable javascript for WKWebView, here is how to do it:**

##### iOS 14 and above:

```
webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
```

##### iOS 13 and below:

```
webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureWebView()
    currentWebView.load(requestURL)
}

private func configureWebView() {
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    /// javaScript 사용 여부
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        let preferences = WKWebpagePreferences()
        preferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences = preferences
    }
    else {
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        /// user interaction없이 윈도우 창을 열 수 있는지 여부를 나타냄. iOS에서는 기본값이 false이다.
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    }
}

func createNewWebView(_ config: WKWebViewConfiguration) -> WKWebView {
    /// autoLayout 되어 있는 webView와 frame을 같게 한다.
    let newWebView = WKWebView(frame: webView.frame,
                               configuration: config)
    newWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    newWebView.uiDelegate = self
    newWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    view.addSubview(newWebView)
    popupWebViews.append(newWebView)
    return newWebView
}
```