# WKWebView not working even after enabling Javascript - Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to show a webView and its contents using WKWebView. I used the below code, and the webView shows its content. The thing is, there is a function to show an auto fill drop down when clicking a button/ textfield inside the webView. And which is working fine on android after enabling the javascript, But it doesn't work for me even if I enable the javascript as per the code below. (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47038285/5416775)

```
private var webView: WKWebView!

   let preferences = WKPreferences()
   preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
   let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
   configuration.preferences = preferences
   webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
```

And the function which the php team uses the below code to show the drop down dynamically.

```
$('input[name=\'option\']').autocomplete({
 'source': function(request, response) {
   $.ajax({
 url: 'index.php?route=product/product_option/autocomplete&language_id=<?php echo $language_id; ?>&store_id=<?php echo $store_id; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
 dataType: 'json',     
 success: function(json) {
   response($.map(json, function(item) {
     return {
       category: item['category'],
       label: item['name'],
       value: item['option_id'],
       type: item['type'],
       option_value: item['option_value']
         }
       }));
     }
   });
 },
 'select': function(item) {
   html  = '<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-option' + option_row + '">';
    html += ' <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_id]" value="" />';
   html += ' <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][name]" value="' + item['label'] + '" />';
   html += ' <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][option_id]" value="' + item['value'] + '" />';
   html += ' <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][type]" value="' + item['type'] + '" />';

   if (item['type'] == 'checkbox') {
   html += ' <div class="form-group">';
   html += '   <label class="col-sm-12 control-label text-danger"><?php echo $entry_text_required; ?></label>';
   html += ' </div>';
   }

   html += ' <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">';
   html += '   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-required' + option_row + '"><?php echo $entry_required; ?></label>';
   html += '   <div class="col-sm-10"><select name="product_option[' + option_row + '][required]" id="input-required' + option_row + '" class="form-control">';
   html += '       <option value="1"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>';
   html += '       <option value="0"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>';
   html += '   </select></div>';
   html += ' </div>';

   html += ' <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">';
   html += '   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-option-sort-order' + option_row + '"><?php echo $entry_option_sort_order; ?></label>';
var option_row = <?php echo $option_row; ?>;
```

Any solution..? would be appreciated. Thanks..!

Comment: please share your Html string which contains your dropdown

Comment: Check your php page's javascript. it's commented out. i.e. will not execute anywhere

Comment: @SahilManchanda, as im new to coding i couldn't get you. can you explain me in detail?

Comment: @Saravanan, try your url on desktop and see if it's presenting any options on select

Comment: I tried it on FireFox (iMac) and it's not showing any options there.

Comment: @Saravanan, I've added an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your new url and it's working perfectly fine. Try to use below Code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    let webView: WKWebView = {
        let v = WKWebView()
        return v
    }()

    lazy var backButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        v.clipsToBounds = true
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        v.setTitle("<", for: .normal)
        v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        return v
    }()

    var url: String?
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?


    func setupUI(){
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        activityIndicator?.center = self.view.center
        [webView,backButton,activityIndicator!].forEach{view.addSubview($0)}
        webView.fillSuperView()
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            backButton.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, size: .init(width: 30, height: 30), padding: .init(top: 8, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0))
        } else {
             backButton.anchor(top: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, left: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, size: .init(width: 30, height: 30), padding: .init(top: 8, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0))
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelect(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func didSelect(_ sender: UIView){
        switch sender {
        case backButton:
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: url ?? "https://demo.dukanje.com/index.php?route=product/product_option&product_id=206&store_id=52&language_id=1")!))
        activityIndicator?.startAnimating()
    }
}

extension WebViewController: WKNavigationDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
        self.activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.activityIndicator = nil
    }
}
```

I've used extensions to help layout:

```
extension UIView{

    func fillSuperView(){
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        guard let superview = superview else {return}
        anchor(top: superview.topAnchor, left: superview.leadingAnchor, bottom: superview.bottomAnchor, right: superview.trailingAnchor)
    }



    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, size: CGSize = .zero, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero){
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let top = top{
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top != 0 ? padding.top : 0).isActive = true
        }
        if let left = left{
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: padding.left != 0 ? padding.left : 0).isActive = true
        }
        if let bottom = bottom{
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: padding.bottom != 0 ? -padding.bottom : 0).isActive = true
        }
        if let right = right{
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: padding.right != 0 ? -padding.right : 0).isActive = true
        }
        if size.width != 0{
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
        }
        if size.height != 0{
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

**First**:
[image]
**Second**:
[image]

Comment: its working fine now. it was my php team issue. anyway thanks for your effort.

Answer (score -1):

1) Allow NSAppTransportSecurity into Plist File.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

2) import WebKit

3) Create @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

4) In ViewDidLoad write this code

```
  let imgUrl = "http://demo.dukanje.com/index.php?route=product/product_option&product_id=206&store_id=cWJaWkdNcTBSVHRtYkkyaDRjK0laQT09..52&language_id=1"
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><p><select>\(imgUrl)</select></p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)

    }
```

Comment: i have already added NSAppTransportSecurity. And tried your code by loading html string but it doesn't even shows the actual content itself.